# sqlite - rollback to a snapshot

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I am developing an application for `android` and `ios`. I want to be able to snapshot a `sqlite` database, and have the possibility of rolling back to that snapshot after many commits. There only needs to be one snapshot at any one time.

The **data must persist over app restarts**, so `SAVEPOINT` is not an option (it only exists within the one connection)

Is this possible with sqlite on android and ios? If not, is there a database solution which does have this ability?

Comment: use Android SQLite Transaction rollback facility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no built-in mechanism to revert committed transactions.

In theory, you could use the [backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) to make a copy of the database files, but in practice, the Android framework does not give you access to this.
If you can ensure that nobody is accessing the database, you could copy the DB files manually.

If the amount of changes is small compared to the size of the entire database, it might be a better idea to record all changes, and revert them manually, when needed.
This is best done using triggers; see [Automatic Undo/Redo Using SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/undoredo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Given that you say *"after so-many **commits**"* in your original post, I'm afraid that you must be referring to a notion that SQLite *(like **every**-other SQL database ...)* most-unfortunately does not directly support. You're going to need to implement "something *application-specific"* within your own application.

And, unfortunately, *"you* must take it from here." SQL understands "atomic transactions" that are concluded either by "commits" or "rollbacks," but it understands nothing *more* than this.

To accomplish your aim, you must delve into (application-specific) realms that IBM once called "checkpoint/restart." But these, most unfortunately, are *completely* "application specific!"

Answer (score -2):

You have to set transaction and you have to commit that transaction if it succeed else you have to cancel that transaction.

below is the sample code

> start transaction

```
database.beginTransaction(); /* for start transaction */
```

> after completing operation on database you can use

```
database.setTransactionSuccessful();    
database.endTransaction();
```

> But if you give error in between transaction

then don't set `database.setTransactionSuccessful();` **so that the transaction will be rollback.**

Thats simple steps.
http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Comment: OP wants to revert after a successful transaction